# Intellij finds .class files instead of .java files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

After merging some code, Intellij builds my project with a mix of `.java` files and `.class` files.

Also when im searching in Intellij (ctrl+shift+n) intellij cant find a few `.java` files. It only shows me the `.class` files of this file. But i can find the files via file structure.

I already reimported the `pom` files. I also deleted the whole project and pulled it again from bitbucket, the problem still stays. When i pull the project from another machine, I dont have this problem.

Thx for help

edit: So i found out the real Problem. I got 3 Modules, but only 2 where decalred as Modules. And i cant mark the Module as an Module, because I deleted some necessary files.

Comment: Clone again in a new location.

Comment: Simple as it sounds... Thx for the help. Maybe it was, because i imported it with a snapshot... Anyway thx for the help!

Comment: My guess is that you have IntelliJ's own files in your commit, and the merge broke some of them.  Add ".idea/" and  "*.iml" to your .gitignore file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a problem cannot be reproduced with a fresh clone in a different location, then it is most likely InteliJs project files that has been put under git control, and then later failed to merge properly subtly breaking functionality.

I would save any work done in this directory, clone anew, apply the saved work, and delete the broken directory.  Then I would ensure that `.idea/` and `*.iml` was removed from git control, and listed in  `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to project structure-> modules and add directory dependency of your file in the dependencies tab. It will show the .java files after that.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when you have Maven dependencies between modules in your project.

The particular case is when you update your dependency in Maven to point at a release version, e.g. `1.0.1`, but the code for the dependency in your project still has a snapshot version in its pom.xml (e.g. 1.0-SNAPSHOT).

IN that case, IntelliJ will load .class files for release version from your Maven repository rather than the .java version from your snapshot version in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem because the **'java'** and **'test'** folders in the cloned project from GitHub were not labeled **'Source Root'** and **'Test Source Root'** respectively.

You could:

- right click on "java" or "test" folder
- click "Mark directory as"
- choose the right one